# Can I force Bing to reindex our site?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, bing

Our website is ranking quite well (first page) on Google for quite a lot of keywords.

However, our website is not on the first 10 pages of Bing for most of these keywords.

I notice our Google rankings have increased since I upgraded our website to Wordpress, and submitted the new sitemap to Google.  Google re-indexed our site within 24 hours of submitting a new sitemap.

I've submitted our sitemap to Bing, but I notice Bing's index of our site still contains our old site's pages, 5 days after submitting our new sitemap, even though Bing has crawled URLs in our sitemap.

Is there a way I can force Bing to re-index our site, or do I just have to be patient?

What is the normal frequency of the Bing bot revisiting a site?

What is the normal frequency of the Bing bot revisiting a site after deleting the old sitemap and submitting a new sitemap?

Thanks.

Comment: 5 days after submitting our sitemap. Seriously? Bing's not Google. You're lucky if they index more than half your site in six months.

Comment: Bing is slow, your lucky to get it that fast as Fiasco said so... allow for months and months with Bing. I waited a whole year for a 50 page site to get 50% indexed

Comment: this has changed a lot. I submitted my website to google and bing at the same time (it was March 2021) and bing displayed it within and hour and google within 12 hours.

Answer (score 1):

No need to force Bing to crawl your pages. Bing is much slower than Google. You will have to wait at least 1-2 months.

Answer (score 1):

Bing and Google are two different search engines and their algorithms are quite different.
There is a vast difference in the way how google indexes websites and that done by Bing.
Crawling for bing and google is different.

Another option is to focus on inorganic search results.

Bing does something similar to what google adwords does in the search and content network.
Bing has collaborated with Yahoo for the contextual ads as well.

If your business is suffering because of the delay in the organic search results, you can depend on the inorganic search results for that period of time.

Personally, I would suggest you to wait for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Bingbot crawling is very slow.  Bing does not indexing sites like Google.  Google and Bing are two different search engine and their crawling bot are much different.  My site is ranked well on Google however, half of it is not indexed on Bing because of Bing's slow crawling.

But there is one way to index site fast on Bing. You can try this with this method.  One of my sites got indexed on Bing in few weeks using it. So, how you can index your site fast on Bing:

1. Resubmitting your sitemap on Bing.
2. Each day fetch a URL from your site.  Fetch the main domain of your site and a few other URLs of your site.
3. Create a link to your site from another of your sites which is already well ranked on Bing.  Make sure the index rate of that site is quite good on Bing as well.
4. Create web 2.0 and create a link to your home page.  Then submit web 2.0 on Bing webmaster from another Bing webmaster account and keep updating web 2.0.
5. Share your site on social media and generate good social signals.
6. Search your site's home page daily on Bing .
7. Build back links from authority sites.

These techniques will index a site on Bing quickly and also improve rankings.